# Why does the UI thread get blocked when running something in a different thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, events

Suppose I have normal `button.Click` event.

If I try to access UI elements from inside of this event I could potentially got unwanted behavior - or even an exception (when debugging). The usual exception in such a scenario is: `...cannot access UI elements from thread different than they were created in`.

Since this is another thread (different than the main) why my UI is blocked when I perform time consuming operations in an event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the framework here? winform? WPF?

In winform (for a click event), you *are* on the UI thread. So you *can* just talk to the UI from the click event. If something else is happening, then there is something wrong. Are you sure you aren't in a timer-callback?

In the more general sense, you can use `InvokeRequired`/`Invoke` etc to pass control to the UI thread.

Comment: How can you tell that some events run in UI thread and others not ?

Comment: By reading the documentation for the event. Most UI-related events will fire on the UI thread. If unsure, check InvokeRequired.

Comment: If the Event fires in thread OTHER than UI it will not prevent window from being refreshed but if it will fire in UI thread the window will not be redrawn until event closes?